# Master Sitemap link in Header of site or Robots.txt

Tags: sitemap

I have a master sitemap that contains links to other site maps that is accessable on a path like:

```
www.website.com/sitemap.xml
```

I wanted to ask if this is enough for the search engines or if I need to link this to my site?

linking - I know I can use a robots.txt file but I is it possible to just add a link to the head of the site - something like (and I'm just guessing):

```
<head>
     <link rel="sitemap" type="application/xml" title="Sitemap" href="/sitemap.xml">
</head>
```

thankyou
Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is totally okay.

Sitemap should always be located in the `root` and that is the only place where the search engines will look.

I suggest you to use a `Google Webmasters` tool to submit a sitemap for your domain so you can get indexed and you can monitor search engine behavior.

Hopefully this info will help you.